# Is there a way to group some columns into an array of columns? postgresql

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I have a query where I get the client information, his loan and each payment that exceeds 30% of the agreed amount. Like if you had to pay 20 dollars and paid 30, it will show that payment. The thing is all the client data repeats if you make two or three payments in the same period. I already make that query. But for the report, I want to group that payment data into an array (I'm using rails and its to slow to make it with its methods) to print in an xlsx view. All the render part is done.
The thing is convert the output from the query to the one that i expected:

```
  Columns      |   type     |
-----------------------------
|fullname      |text        |  <--- From this
|id_number     |string      |
|loan          |string      |
|obligation    |numeric     |
|balance       |numeric     |
|loan_start    |date        |  <--- Until here, are the data that will repeat. (client data)
|code          |string      |  <--- from this and below are the columns that change for each
|pmt_date      |date        |       payment. (payment data)
|bill_amt      |numeric     |
|pmt_amt       |numeric     |
|dif           |numeric     |  <--- This is the difference between bill_amount and amount
|note          |text        |
-----------------------------
```

The output that I want:

```
  Columns      |   type     |
-----------------------------
|fullname      |text        |  <--- From this
|id_number     |string      |
|loan          |string      |
|obligation    |numeric     |
|balance       |numeric     |
|loan_start    |date        |  <--- Until here (client data)
|payments      |array       |  <--- each array will have an array with the payment data or json
|totals        |array       |  <--- This will have the sum of bill_amt, pmt_amt and dif
-----------------------------
```

```
This is actual query: 
SELECT
  alert.id,
  payment.codigo AS code,
  alertable_type,
  payment.payment_date AS date,
  lm.lm AS charge,
  amount AS amount,
  amount - lm.lm AS dif,
  ac.comment AS note,
  fn.full_name AS fullname,
  client.id_number AS cedula,
  loan.codigo AS loan,
  loan.total_loan_amt AS obligation,
  ch.sum AS balance,
  loan.loan_start_date AS pmt_start
FROM 
  prestamas.alerts AS alert
JOIN prestamas.payments AS payment
ON alert.alertable_id = payment.id
JOIN prestamas.loans AS loan
ON payment.loan_id = loan.id
JOIN (
  SELECT
    CASE 
      WHEN loan_periodicity = 'Quincenal'
        THEN payment_amt * 2
    ELSE payment_amt
    END AS lm,
    id
  FROM prestamas.loans
) AS lm
ON loan.id = lm.id
JOIN (
  SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN delete_comment IS NOT NULL THEN delete_comment
      WHEN solve_comment IS NOT NULL THEN solve_comment
      WHEN investigate_comment IS NOT NULL THEN investigate_comment
      WHEN read_comment IS NOT NULL THEN read_comment
      ELSE 'No se ha leído la Alerta'
    END AS "comment",
    id
  FROM prestamas.alerts
) AS ac
ON ac.id = alert.id
JOIN prestamas.clients AS client
ON client.id = loan.client_id
JOIN (
  SELECT
    CONCAT(
      TRIM(first_name),
      ' ',
      TRIM(last_name),
      ' ',
      TRIM(apellido_materno)
    ) AS full_name,
    id
  FROM prestamas.clients
) AS fn
ON fn.id = client.id
JOIN (
  SELECT
    SUM(balance) AS "sum",
    l.id AS "id"
  FROM prestamas.loans AS l
  JOIN prestamas.charges AS ch
  ON ch.loan_id = l.id
  GROUP BY l.id
) AS ch
ON ch.id = loan.id
WHERE alertable_type = 'Payment'
AND payment.payment_date >= DATE('2020-09-01') 
AND payment.payment_date <= DATE('2020-09-26')
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please show us your exising query, along with the current data you are getting as a result, and the result you want.

Comment: By now i dont have any result that repeats bc is a demo db. But there is the query. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I get this solution:

```
SELECT
  id,
  fullname AS "Nombre del cliente",
  id_number AS "Ruc o Cédula",
  loan AS "N° Préstamo",
  loan_start AS "Fecha",
  obligation AS "M.Obligacióm",
  balance AS "Saldo Prest.",
  json_agg(                             <-- using json_agg to make an array of
    json_build_array(                       payments and json_build_array to make
      code,                                 an array with each payment data
      pmt_date,
      bill_amt,
      pmt_amt,
      dif,
      TRIM(
        regexp_replace(
          note, 
          E'[\\n\\r---]+', 
          ' ', 
          'g' 
        )
      )
    )
  ) AS payments,
  json_build_array(                     <-- make an array for the sum of charge
    sum(charge),
    sum(amount),
    sum(dif)
  )
FROM (
  SELECT
    client.id AS id,
    payment.codigo AS code,
    alertable_type,
    payment.payment_date AS date,
    lm.lm AS bill_amt,
    amount AS pmt_amt,
    amount - lm.lm AS dif,
    ac.comment AS note,
    fn.full_name AS fullname,
    client.id_number AS id_number,
    loan.codigo AS loan,
    loan.total_loan_amt AS obligation,
    ch.sum AS balance,
    loan.loan_start_date AS loan_start
  FROM 
    prestamas.alerts AS alert
  JOIN prestamas.payments AS payment
  ON alert.alertable_id = payment.id
  JOIN prestamas.loans AS loan
  ON payment.loan_id = loan.id
  JOIN (
    SELECT
      CASE 
        WHEN loan_periodicity = 'Quincenal'
          THEN payment_amt * 2
      ELSE payment_amt
      END AS lm,
      id
    FROM prestamas.loans
  ) AS lm
  ON loan.id = lm.id
  JOIN (
    SELECT
      CASE
        WHEN delete_comment IS NOT NULL THEN delete_comment
        WHEN solve_comment IS NOT NULL THEN solve_comment
        WHEN investigate_comment IS NOT NULL THEN investigate_comment
        WHEN read_comment IS NOT NULL THEN read_comment
        ELSE 'No se ha leído la Alerta'
      END AS "comment",
      id
    FROM prestamas.alerts
  ) AS ac
  ON ac.id = alert.id
  JOIN prestamas.clients AS client
  ON client.id = loan.client_id
  JOIN (
    SELECT
      CONCAT(
        TRIM(first_name),
        ' ',
        TRIM(last_name),
        ' ',
        TRIM(apellido_materno)
      ) AS full_name,
      id
    FROM prestamas.clients
  ) AS fn
  ON fn.id = client.id
  JOIN (
    SELECT
      SUM(balance) AS "sum",
      l.id AS "id"
    FROM prestamas.loans AS l
    JOIN prestamas.charges AS ch
    ON ch.loan_id = l.id
    GROUP BY l.id
  ) AS ch
  ON ch.id = loan.id
  WHERE alertable_type = 'Payment'
  AND payment.payment_date >= DATE('2020-09-01') 
  AND payment.payment_date <= DATE('2020-09-29')
) AS raw
GROUP BY 
  id, 
  fullname, 
  id_number, 
  loan,
  loan_start,
  obligation,
  balance
;
```

Getting the output that I wish.

```
  Columns      |   type     |
-----------------------------
|fullname      |text        |  <--- From this
|id_number     |string      |
|loan          |string      |
|obligation    |numeric     |
|balance       |numeric     |
|loan_start    |date        |  <--- Until here (client data)
|payments      |json        |  <--- each array will have an array with the payment data or json
|totals        |json        |  <--- This will have the sum of bill_amt, pmt_amt and dif
-----------------------------
```

Thank you very much to every one that try or want to help!